# Sweat the small stuff - motivational quote - what does it mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

sweat the small stuff - quote by Robin Sharma.

Comment: Don't sweat the small stuff.  (American informal):
something that you say in order to tell someone not to worry about things that are not important Don't sweat the small stuff, Sam. It's just office gossip - no one takes it seriously.
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Don%27t+sweat+the+small+stuff

Comment: Conversely, "Sweat the small stuff" = "Pay attention to the details"; people notice when you don't put in the effort to truly finish something and make it look as perfect as you can.

Comment: From *[sweat](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sweat): 1.4 (Of a person) exert a great deal of strenuous effort; 1.5 (Of a person) be or remain in a state of extreme anxiety, typically for a prolonged period; 1.6 [with object] North American informal: Worry about (something)* [ODO].

Comment: According to Ngram, first seems to have been used about 1960, so not Robin Sharma's

Comment: @Christopher The original quote "don't sweat the small stuff" is older, yes.  The OP's question is referring to a motivational quote, "sweat the small stuff", which could easily have been constructed by anyone multiple times since the older quote has existed.  Sharma's use is probably not original, but I think the concern is more about the meaning and not the source.

Comment: @Cord Clearly. It would be incorrect to attribute the origin to the wrong person.

Comment: @Christopher Only if it were an original thought, which, as a single phrase, it's not.  If someone, as a platitude, said to you, "don't sweat the small stuff" and you responded "well, I want to sweat the small stuff", you would not be accused of plagiarizing Sharma's motivational speech.  If Sharma told his audience "don't let others' behavior destroy your inner peace", I would not say he was plagiarizing the Dalai Lama.  If the OP says he got this quote from Sharma, I assume that's true.

Comment: It's an example of reverse proverbial wisdom, where someone takes a position opposite to the one expressed in a familiar aphorism—like "Cry over spilt milk," or "Count your chickens before they're hatched," or "Let the bed bugs bite." I'm not sure how much actual wisdom is contained in these counter-proverbs, but they certainly are attention getters.

Comment: @Cord *"quote by"* is given to the first person who said the quote

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The traditional quote is "don't sweat the small stuff": do not let yourself worry about unnecessary details since the big picture is what really matters.  Sharma's quote is basically a counter to this.  He is saying that the details are what actually matter and you had better worry about them if you want the big picture to succeed.

Answer (score -1):

What the person is saying is that you shouldn't worry about anything that is so little and is not a major life changing experience because you should waste your time stressing about that for sure :)
https://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t+sweat+the+small+stuff&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=657&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwii3IbltrLLAhUMvIMKHQn0B9cQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=don%27t+sweat+the+small+stuff+meme&imgrc=E751WdUC4dlTPM%3A

Comment: You don't seem to have noticed that the OP's quote omits the "don't".

Answer (score -2):

Sweat the small stuff and let the big stuff tale cre of itself ...,...the big stuff is too big to change or yor opinion,one voice or any action won't make any difference....the small stuff can escalate and b life changing on micro levels....especially between partners....the small stuff can turn into big stuff.....obviously it's all relevant to the circumstance but I like this version better

Comment: Hi Fast bin, welcome to English SE. Can you illuminate this answer with some references? That is according to site policy, if lacking you'll attract down-votes/closure. Without it its more like an opinion which would belong in a comment instead.